# RK45 ode solver python3

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, ode

How to use this [function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.RK45.html) please?

I have a function that return list of right-hand side differential equations `right(t, x0)`.

```
import scipy.integrate as ode
t, r =ode.RK45(right(t, x0), t0, tmax, dt)
```

The error:

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

What should be the first argument please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass the function as object, not a function value, thus

```
solver = ode.RK45(right)
solver.set_initial(y0,t0)
```

and then in a loop over `solver.integrate` you compute the desired integration steps, see the examples in the documentation.

If you have any recent version of `scipy`, then use the newer `solve_ivp` interface, where you provide everything in one call

```
solution = solve_ivp(right, [t0, tmax], y0, method = "RK45", t_eval = np.arange(t0,tmax,dt))
```

and find the solution components in `solution.t` and `solution.y`, where the latter is a tuple of the time series of each state component.